# "custom agents" vs. "customs agents"

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

Does one write "custom agents" or "customs agents"? I saw both:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=U.S._Customs_and_Border_Protection&oldid=1064179946): "US and Canadian **custom** agents".
- [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/list-of-customs-agents-and-fast-parcel-operators): "Search the register of **customs** agents and fast parcel operators".

Comment: The wiki article you point at uses "Customs" in every place except one. Looks like a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normally called "customs" (e.g., "[U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://www.cbp.gov/)"), so the plural is better. Also, "custom" could be confused with the adjective "custom", which has a very different meaning. [Google Books ngrams confirms that the plural is usual.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=custom%20agent%2Ccustoms%20agent&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccustom%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccustoms%20agent%3B%2Cc0)